What is the missing configuration step in VSCode rdbg Ruby Debugger "Can not find attachable Ruby process."?
"Can not find attachable Ruby process."
When following the setup to install the 'vscode rdbg ruby debugger' extension, at the launch of the Debug & Run, the message alert "Can not find attachable Ruby process." shows. What to add to the launch.json file, or rails server so that it finds the process?


Add "debugPort": "1234", so the launch.json looks like:
{
  "type": "rdbg",
  "name": "Attach with rdbg",
  "request": "attach",
  "debugPort": "1234"
}


bundle exec rdbg --open -n -c --port 1234 bin/rails s



something like you installed multiple versions of gem debug, then rdbg can't automatically find current rails server debug socks file path.
you can add "rdbgPath": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rdbg" to launch.json
    {
      "type": "rdbg",
      "name": "Attach with rdbg",
      "request": "attach",
      "rdbgPath": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rdbg",
    }

then run bundle binstub debug to generate bin/rdbg. Now, debug should work.
